# CRL date formats and conversion from GMT to epoch

Tags: openssl, x.509, c

I am running few security algorithms on my product and would like know few general details about the CRLs (Certificate Revocation Lists).

I am using the following command `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in signed.p7s >> sign_extract.txt` to extract the information(crls) from my CA signed file(signed.p7s).Based on the string "id-smime-aa-timeStampToken" i am extracting the time information from offset and length of that particular field (sign_extract.txt). Below is the extracted time stamp

> Time stamp: Oct  8 15:04:56 2020 GMT Accuracy: 0x02 seconds,
>
> unspecified millis, unspecified micros

**My questions are:**

1. The time present in CRL, is it always going to be in GMT or can have different format?

Most of my devices are set with some old date, so when running my algorithms i am extracting the time info as above and run my secure algorithms for validity of certificates.

2. Is it ok if we extract using "id-smime-aa-timeStampToken" or we have any other generic way?
3. My final aim is convert the time into unix epoch,is there any generic way to do that?

EDIT 1: This is from the example of man page `timegm`, on how to set & clear the timezone once the conversion is complete. Added just for the completeness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm tm;
    char buf[255];
    char *tz;
    tz = getenv("TZ");
    if (tz)
        tz = strdup(tz);
    setenv("TZ", "", 1);
    tzset();

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    strptime("Oct 8 15:04:56 2020 GMT", "%B %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT", &tm);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s", &tm);

    if (tz) {
       setenv("TZ", tz, 1);
      free(tz);
    } else
     unsetenv("TZ");
    tzset();
    puts(buf);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: RFC 5280 &sect;4.1.2.5.1 and &sect;4.1.2.5.2 state Validity times must be in Greenwich Mean Time (Zulu).  Not sure about your #2 and #3 though; #3 depends on how you're doing all this (shell script? Python? C?)

Comment: thanks @gowenfawr for letting me know the #1, for #2 and #3 am trying to use linux utilities like `date` command and functions like `maketime` `locatime` in `C` would like to know is there any generic way

Comment: The `date` command can convert to epoch time, e.g. `date --date='Oct 8 15:04:56 2020 GMT' '+%s'`.  The '+%s' tells it to output seconds since the epoch.

Comment: Yes, infact i am using something similar `date -d "Jul 10 15:20:25 2020 GMT" +%s` , only problem with that is i will have to invoke that command using `system` function and write the output to some file, instead if i use standard functions it will be better, but is there something which works universally? i checked `time.h` which has lot of functions, i would like to get suggestions if someone has already done this kind of thing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. RFC 5280 §4.1.2.5.1 and §4.1.2.5.2 state Validity times must be in Greenwich Mean Time (Zulu).
2. I don't know.  A better way than dumping text to a file?  I'm not clear what you're looking for here.
3. Using C, you can use `strptime()` to convert the string into a time structure, and `strftime()` to convert that time structure into epoch seconds.  This modified example comes from [man strptime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct tm tm;
  char buf[255];      
  memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
  /* Because strptime doesn't actually handle timezone */
  setenv("TZ", "", 1);
  tzset();
  strptime("Oct 8 15:04:56 2020 GMT", "%B %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z", &tm);
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s", &tm);
  puts(buf);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And as you can see, it prints out the epoch time for the time string you've provided:

```
$ ./foo
1602169496
$
```

Comment: When i execute your program my output is `1602149696` , the difference is `19800` which is `+5.30 hrs` , but `date -d "Oct 8 15:04:56 2020 GMT" +%s` is showing `1602169496` , why am i seeing the difference? Is it because we are in different time zones? do you also get the same output with `date -d "Oct 8 15:04:56 2020 GMT" +%s`

Comment: Yes, I get the same output (1602169496) using that `date` command.  My system is actually set to UTC,  so there's no local time adjustment from GMT for my numbers.  Are you in a GMT +5:30 time zone?

Comment: yes i am in GMT +5.30 my `date` command shows `Thu Oct 29 07:01:41 IST 2020` currently, but how is that `date` is properly converting by making use `tz`, but the standard functions does not, what do i have to do to make my standard functions behave same as `date` command ? make use of `tzset()`? that is exactly what i want avoid because i dont want to change anything on my device, just want converted time thats all!

Comment: if i add `setenv("TZ", "", 1); tzset();` before `strptime` i am getting `1602169496`, but i am looking for without using  `tzset();`

Comment: Try also the fix to the `strptime` line I edited in (replace GMT with %Z).  I'm not seeing it fix anything but it's the correct way to do it :) and heck ymmv

Comment: Looks like it's a [bug in `strptime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556260/c-c-strptime-does-not-parse-z-timezone-name) so your `tzset` fix may be your only option.

Comment: Updated code to incorporate OP's fix for strptime not handling timezone.

Comment: looks that way , i must use `tzset()` to achieve the proper result, thanks for staying with me so far and support, had a nice chat with you.

Comment: `strftime %s` is not guaranteed by standard C or POSIX, although it is in GNU and (even more widely used) Olson.